# Как узнать сколько строк на html сайте

Tags: java, html

Мне просто нужно узнать сколько всего строк в html странице где будут данные подобного вида 
"World:5"
Мне нужные эти данные только для split', чтоб в проекте просто понимало сколько там этих данных, либо вы можете предложить свой более лёгкий способ.

Заранее спасибо, буду благодарен любой помощи.

Comment: На гитхабе есть Count lines of code посмотри может он тебе подойдет

Comment: Посмотрел, но оно мне не подходит.                  Но,все же спасибо, что пытался мне помочь.

Comment: Уточните, пожалуйста, шаблон поиска. Имеется в виду <слово>:<число>?

Comment: Да, слово и число(int, float не имеет значения). Главное просто, чтобы обрабатывались все данные на сайте, которые будут пополняться. Чтобы грубо говоря слово уходило в String а число в int или float, как уже говорил - разницы не имеет.